# Pulling data from MySQL for Feed

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site where people generate content. My database has a table called _conv and inside there is several fields with Name, Text, ect.

How can i write something a simple php script to just pull that data and display it like a feed on a webpage? If anyone could give me some tips or a link that can help me do this that would be awesome.

My programmer designed the site, but i can easily figure this out if given the right direction.

It would be like say the last 10 submissions on my table, and it would display downwards like a feed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need to `SELECT` it from the table using either

- ORDER BY autoincrementfield DESC (if your primary key is INT / BIGINT / MEDIUMINT / ... and is set to auto_increment)
- ORDER BY insertdatefield DESC (else you need a field with a date when the entry was inserted - order it in that case)

After `ORDER BY` you should `LIMIT 10` the result.

Comment: Awesome and how can i format what it would look like on my page? Thats what im confused about.

Comment: Should i just make a layout of it code it in html and insert the values taht will be displayed there?

Comment: yes :) just display it via html

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 10");
if(mysql_mun_rows($query) == 1){
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
// and then you can fetch data 
$name = $result['NAME'];
$text= $result['TEXT'];

}
```

Comment: Wow this is great now i know what to do. :D Thanks!